# Django test setup fails when running single test file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

The immediate symptoms:

```
$ pytest …/apps/users/test/test_graph_permissions_command.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-4.6.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
Django settings: dms.settings (from ini file)
rootdir: /src/app, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: forked-1.0.2, celery-4.3.0, django-3.5.0, cov-2.7.1, xdist-1.28.0
collected 1 item                                                               

…/apps/users/test/test_graph_permissions_command.py E

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_ ERROR at setup of TestGraphPermissionsCommand.test_should_resolve_a_permission_hierarchy _
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py:519: in _django_setup_unittest
    request.getfixturevalue("django_db_setup")
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:108: in django_db_setup
    **setup_databases_args
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py:174: in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:80: in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:123: in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py:128: in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py:90: in serialize
    for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:120: in get_objects
    yield from queryset.iterator()
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:341: in _iterator
    yield from self._iterable_class(self, chunked_fetch=use_chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polymorphic/query.py:56: in _polymorphic_iterator
    o = next(base_iter)
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:55: in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1087: in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:474: in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:54: in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:45: in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:219: in get_select
    cols = self.get_default_columns()
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:666: in get_default_columns
    column = field.get_col(alias)
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:981: in get_col
    output_field = self.target_field
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:878: in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:632: in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:619: in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:604: in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
E   ValueError: Related model 'appname.ModelName' cannot be resolved
=========================== 1 error in 5.54 seconds ============================
```

The test file:

```
$ cat …/apps/users/test/test_graph_permissions_command.py
from django.test import TestCase


class TestGraphPermissionsCommand(TestCase):
    def test_should_resolve_a_permission_hierarchy(self) -> None:
        pass
```

The circumstances:

1. Testing test_graph_permissions_command.py with *another* file works fine - any other file seems to work, and it works whether test_graph_permissions_command.py is first or last.
2. Importing `TestCase` from `unittest` instead works, but I will need some things from `django.test.TestCase` in the actual test.
3. Testing any *other* single file also works.
4. I rebuild the VM that this runs on every night, and a colleague was able to reproduce this issue, so it's not unique to my setup.
5. `./manage.py makemigrations` reports "No changes detected".
6. Many other test classes inherit from the same `TestCase` class without issue.
7. The app and model in the error message is very well tested. Ditto for the two models which each have a `ForeignKey` to `"appname.ModelName"`. The code coverage is 98%.

What is going on here? It looks like this could be caused by a failure of the test DB builder to do things in the right sequence.

Comment: The error message shows that it has issues resolving some model `Related model 'appname.ModelName' cannot be resolved`. Do you have such model `ModelName` in an app `appname`? if not, can you check to see if any of those names are mentioned anywhere in your project?

Comment: @Ken4scholars Please read the entire question. I am able to run the test with another test file, so the issue is not that the other model isn't declared.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should ignore the error message returned. Else what else would one use to infer what the issue is? I clearly read the question and if there is an error message, you should clearly be trying to see why it is returned

Comment: I've worked on figuring out the error message for some hours now with the help of a colleague. What part of the question leads you to believe I've ignored it? What I simply cannot understand is why running a *single* file makes a difference, and why this model (referenced in 107 places elsewhere and tested extensively) is not initialized in this context. We currently have 98% coverage of the code base, in case that gives you an idea of how weird this is.

Comment: Your first answer made it sound that way. I simply asked about the obvious error message shown and you made it sound like one shouldn't even look in that direction. Anyway, if you keep getting that error the same exact model then you really ought to check the definition. Maybe something in the app's init method or something. As it is now, there's very little information for one to go on. It could be that needed setup modules are not imported properly when you run only one file as opposed to running all files